# How can I resolve "SparkException: Exception thrown in Future.get" issue?

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm working on two pyspark dataframes and doing a left-anti join on them to track everyday changes and then send an email.
The first time I tried:

```
diff = Table_a.join(
    Table_b, 
    [Table_a.col1== Table_b.col1, Table_a.col2== Table_b.col2], 
    how='left_anti'
)
```

Expected output is a pyspark dataframe with some or no data.

This diff dataframe gets it's schema from Table_a. 
The first time I ran it, showed no data as expected with the schema representation. The next time onwards just throws SparkException:

```sh
Exception thrown in Future.get
```

Comment: I ran into the same issue. My use case is that I'm using looker to build BI models and looker would convert my models to spark-sql. In certain cases the queries failed with error  `The Apache Spark 2.0 database encountered an error while running this query.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in Future.get:`

Answer (score 3):

I use Scala, but, from my experience, this happens when one of the underlying tables has been changed somehow. My advice would be to try to run simply
`display(Table_a)` and `display(Table_b)`, and see if any of those commands fail. This should give you a hint about where is the problem.

In any case, to effectively solve the issue, my advice would clearing the cache running

```mysql
%sql
REFRESH my_schema.table_a
REFRESH my_schema.table_b
```

and, then, redefining those variables, as in

```python
Table_a = spark.table("my_schema.table_a")
Table_b = spark.table("my_schema.table_b")
```

This worked for me - hope it helps you too.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Lucas Lima. Every time i create a new table i clear the cache with the following command in pyspark:

```python
table_a.cache()
```

Hope the information helps.

Comment: @Anasta_Sia Should not it be table_a.uncache() instead of table_a.cache()

Answer (score 0):

I was similar type of issue. The root cause of the issue was the data type mismatch.
At that time of saving data one of my column had the data type as IntegerType and when I was loading the same data then I provided incorrect data type in schema hence it was throwing the exception.
This will not throw any exception immediately until you call any action of the data such as **show()** or **count** on the loaded data.

**Error Screenshot:**
[image: Error Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon this when trying to debug this on a delta table.

Turns out that one of the underlying delta files had been deleted manually from the file system:

> A file referenced in the transaction log cannot be found. This occurs when data has been manually deleted from the file system rather than using the table `DELETE` statement. For more information, see https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/databricks/delta/delta-intro#frequently-asked-questions

You can do either of the below to solve this problem.

1. set spark configuration `spark.sql.files.ignoreMissingFiles` to `true`
2. run `fsck repair table tablename` on your underlying delta table (run `fsck repair table tablename DRY RUN` first to see the files)