# Pyspark error: SparkException: Exception thrown in Future.get:

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have the following code:

```
fact_item = (
  spark.table('nn_team7_es.fact_table')
  .union(spark.table('nn_squad7_cs.fact_table'))
  .filter((f.col('date_key').between(start_py, end_py)) | (f.col('date_key').between(start_cy, end_cy)))
  .filter(f.col('source') == 'tickets')
  .filter(f.col('subtype') == 'item')
  .filter(f.col('is_trx_ok') == 1)
  .filter(f.col('is_return_item') == 0)
  .groupby('iso_country_code',
           'store_id',
           'date_key',
           'ticket_id',
           'customer_id',
           'item_id')
  .agg(f.sum('item_quantity').alias('item_quantity'),
       f.sum(f.col('item_extended_amount') - f.col('item_vat_amount')).alias('item_net_amount'))
  .join(dim_dates, on=['date_key'], how='inner')
  .join(dim_stores, on=['store_id'], how='inner')
  .join(dim_products, on=['iso_country_code', 'item_id'], how='left')
  .fillna(value='undefined', subset=['item_description', 'WGI', 'UWG', 'Family', 'Brand'])
)

display(fact_item)
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

> SparkException: Exception thrown in Future.get:

If I run the code without the last display I don't get any error. As I never saw it before when running the code I don't understand why I get it. Any idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I resolve "SparkException: Exception thrown in Future.get" issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56710198/how-can-i-resolve-sparkexception-exception-thrown-in-future-get-issue)

Answer (score 0):

Check for datatypes for the joining columns.
Also, you will see the error only while using **display()** or **count()**, the query would run as expected.

P.S: I was facing the same issue, once I resolved the datatypes mismatch, It was working fine.